# How to fetch another url after the first is complete and display both in a foreach loop

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a beginner question about Blazor with which I am struggling a bit.

The following is a sample code I just made to show the problem:

```
<ul>

    @foreach(var student in classroom) {
 
    }

</ul>


ClassRoomModel classroom; 
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{

  classroom = await ClassRommService.GetClassRoomDetails(); 
}
```

But inside my `foreach` loop, I want to make a second query that uses `student.url` to fetch all student details.

I tried creating another method `GetStudentDetailsById(string url){}` and tried to place it inside the foreach loop as:

```
@foreach(var student in classroom)
{
  await GetStudentDetailsById(student.url)
...
}
```

But Blazor complains saying that it can not use the function inside the loop, and I think the approach might be an antipattern.

How do I create a function that waits until the classroom function returns a JSON and then sends another query to `student.url` to use in the for each loop.

Thank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new component called for example `StudentListItem.razor` and add the logic of fetching the student details inside it. Something like this:

**StudentListItem.razor**:

```
@if (studentDetails != null)
{
    <li>
       ...
    </li>
}

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string Url { get; set; }

    private string currentUrl;
    private StudentDetails studentDetails;

    protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
    {
        if (currentUrl != Url)
        {
            currentUrl = Url;
            studentDetails = await GetStudentDetailsById(currentUrl);            
        }        
    }
}
```

Then use like this:

```
<ul>
    @foreach (var student in classroom) {
        <StudentListItem Url="@student.url" />
    }
</ul>

@code {
    ClassRoomModel classroom;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {    
        classroom = await ClassRommService.GetClassRoomDetails();
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

Alternatively you can fetch all student details inside `OnInitializedAsync` and create a list of the results.

```
@if (studentDetailsList != null)
{
    <ul>
        @foreach (var studentDetails in studentDetailsList)
        {
            ...
        }
    </ul>
}
else
{
    <p>Loading...</p>
}

@code {
    ClassRoomModel classroom;

    IEnumerable<StudentDetails> studentDetailsList;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {    
        classroom = await ClassRommService.GetClassRoomDetails();

        var fetchStudentDetailsTasks = classroom.Select(student => GetStudentDetailsById(student.url));
        studentDetailsList = await Task.WhenAll(fetchStudentDetailsTasks);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way that doesn't use components? I am trying to use a component based on the value fetched from `@student.url` so I already have a dedicated component for it

Comment: thanks for your second answer, but it doesn't show list of students for each classroom. Maybe in my question I didn't clarify but there has to be two foreach loops, the first lists classrooms and i want all students that belong to a classroom to be displayed under the list

Comment: In your code you have `ClassRoomModel` which I assume represents a single classroom. Where is the list of classrooms?